# How to add a MapIcon at clicking location on MapControl in C# Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, dictionary, click, windows-phone-8.1, mouse

I want to add a pinpoint to MapControl at the mouse click position, but I can't find a way to do this. 
Do you guys know a way to do this?

Platform: Windows Phone 8.1 (C#)

Comment: The map's `Tapped` event will give you the screen coordinates.  Use `MapControl.GetLocationFromOffset()` to convert the screen coordinates to map (geographic) coordinates.  Add `MapIcon` using those coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Paul Abbot** answered my question with:

> The map's Tapped event will give you the screen coordinates. Use
>   MapControl.GetLocationFromOffset() to convert the screen coordinates
>   to map (geographic) coordinates. Add MapIcon using those coordinates